# Finishing activity first clears EditTexts and only then does what it should do

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, android-edittext

that's my first post here.
I have problem with managing activities. I have my main activity, which launches other activities containing some EditTexts. Here's the code for launching:

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActualClass.this, NextClass.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
```

I have few EditTexts on the freshly launched activity and some buttons. One of the buttons gets me back to the main activity. On its OnTouchEvent I run simple **finish();** It all seems simple and should work just fine, but when I click the button which should get me back to my main activity, it firstly clears my EditTexts. When I click it for the second time, It finally gets me back to my main activity. What should I do to prevent clearing the EditTexts and get back to my main activity after the first click? I'd really appreciate your help.

Sorry guys, I'm adding more code. So here's the listener which launches the second activity, the one with EditTexts:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.buttonForward:
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActualClass.this, NextClass.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            break;

        default:
            break;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

And on the second activity, where my problem seems to occur, the listener on button looks like this:

```
   buttonBack.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            finish();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And the problem is: when I first click the back button on the second activity, it doesn't get me back to my main activity - it clears all the EditTexts on activity and sets the focus on first element. When I click the button for the second time, it finally gets me back to main activity.

I'm providing full code of the NextClass class, the one with EditTexts.

```
public class NextClass extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.nextclasslayout);

        final EditText firstEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstEditTextName);
        final EditText secondEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondEditTextName);

        ImageButton buttonBack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBack);


        buttonBack.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                finish();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }    

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Folks may be better to help you were you to post complete minimal code necessary to replicate your problem.  I've never had a problem as you've described.

Comment: I am having difficulties understanding what you are saying.  Do you want the button to be pressed twice to go back, or just once?  Also, if you could provide some more code (perhaps your Button's OnTouchEvent class), it would be easier to help you with.

Comment: Have you tried returning true from onTouch? false means you did not handle the event yourself and the touch event is propogated up the view

Comment: Can you post the full code for the Activity with the EditTexts in please? Rather than using an `OnTouchListener` use an `OnClickListener` for button events and override the `onClick` method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html#onClick(android.view.View) . If you are going to use an `OnTouchListener` you need to listen for the correct `MotionEvent` action such as `ACTION_UP` rather than performing it for all touch events. And also you should be returning true from `onTouch` when starting or finishing the activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `EditText`s aren't getting cleared. You just launch two `NextClass` activities because `onTouch()` method is called twice: once for `ACTION_DOWN` and once for `Action_UP`. And when you finish the top-most one, the next one appears. If you use `OnClickListener` in `ActualClass` activity for handling click events from the button, everything should be fine.

Comment: THANKS! This helped a lot. You are right - my activity is being invoked twice.